# How can I set a default sort for tables in PHPMyAdmin (i.e. always "Primary key - Descending")

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Even though its obnoxious in a lot of ways I use PHPMyAdmin all the time to debug database issues while writing PHP. By default it sorts tables by primary key ascending. 99% of the time I would rather have the newest data (my test data) shown at the top by default rather than the useless first few records ever saved.

Is there a way to configure PHPMyAdmin to show the newest records by default? To alter similar behavior?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For anyone else who comes here looking for an answer:

In phpMyAdmin 4.5.0, maybe in earlier versions too, you can set the [$cfg['TablePrimaryKeyOrder']](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_TablePrimaryKeyOrder) config like so:

```
$cfg['TablePrimaryKeyOrder'] = 'DESC';
```

> This defines the default sort order for the tables, having a primary key, when there is no sort order defines externally. Acceptable values : [‘NONE’, ‘ASC’, ‘DESC’]

This sets the default sort if the table has a primary key and that no other sort has been applied to it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It may have came 5 years after the original question was posted, but still a life-saver.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I never marked it as the answer before,  just came back after years and saw it. Not sure why I didn't see the notifications about the comments but oh well. I stopped using PHPMyAdmin long ago but glad this is here for others!

Answer (score 6):

You can save a private bookmark with the name of the table you're browsing.

See https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#bookmarks-can-i-execute-a-default-bookmark-automatically-when-entering-browse-mode-for-a-table

> **6.22 Bookmarks: Can I execute a default bookmark automatically when entering Browse mode for a table?**
>
> Yes. If a bookmark has the same label as a table name and it’s not a public bookmark, it will be executed.

Comment: +1. this works like a charm. should be the one and only accepted answer.

Comment: This is working on 2022. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

i think you can do this. Go to a table -> operations and set alter table order by descending. 
Next time when ever you browse you get the newest row first.

Comment: This is a change to the database itself, not phpMyAdmin, so all applications will be affected by this change (though usually that shouldn't be a big deal). More importantly, **the table will not retain that order after records are inserted or deleted.** So, you'll have to keep going back and altering it whenever records are inserted/deleted. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 3):

@jeremyclarke, in phpMyAdmin v3.4.5, after login click "home"
then,
from "More" menu choose "Settings"
click "Main frame" tab, then "Browse mode" tab

There you'll find "Default sorting order" the default mode is set to SMART
hence, choose "ASC" or "DESC"

If you do the above steps, it will be saved for the current session,

to save it permanently set it in config.php
http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#Order

Comment: The default sort order option only kicks in after you click on a column name.  When you hit the "browse" tab for a table, it'll still show the table rows in the order they were inserted.

Answer (score 1):

> By default it sorts tables by primary
>   key ascending

phpMyAdmin isn't performing any sorting at all by default. It's simply asking for all records in a table and MySQL is deciding the order.

> Is there a way to configure PHPMyAdmin
>   to show the newest records by default?
>   To alter similar behavior?

There's no way to do this as phpMyAdmin would have to be informed about every primary key of every table (assuming there is one, and only one) and how to sort it.

phpMyAdmin does support bookmarking queries. You could DESC and then bookmark that. However, it certainly won't minimize the number of clicks, if that's what you're aim is.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/

Comment: I guess what I need is for PHPMyAdmin to save the last sort state of each table for me and load that when I come back to the table. It seems to remember it within a session but then it resets after the 15 minutes or whatever.

Comment: Actually it is possible just look at the next answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625257/727695

Comment: Fixed! This answer is now wrong I guess, sorry it was left as the accepted answer for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use heidi SQL

Here's a guide on how:

### Enable login from your host pc.

First of all, get your IP Address - http://www.whatismyip.com
Hopefully that's a static IP, otherwise you have some less secure options (below)

You'll need access to create a user on the database. You can do this through Cpanel, or in PHP My Admin (assuming you have the right level of access). Google for instructions if you are unsure. Fail that you can attemtp to run this query:

```
CREATE USER 'jason'@'your_ip_here' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password_here';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'jason'@'your_ip_here';
```

If you don't have a static IP Address then you can consider using a wildcard, although this is less secure. Another more secure option is [SSH tunneling](http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/mysql_ssh_howto.html)

### Download and install Heidi SQL

http://www.heidisql.com/download.php

Run the install (on windows ofcourse)

Finally, setup your connection, connect.

You'll find that heidi allows you to easily sort the listing of data, http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=data
It also remembers sorts and filters too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your PHPMyAdmin configuration file.

in most of PHPMyAdmin versions, the configuration file will be config.inc.php

```
$cfg['TablePrimaryKeyOrder'] = 'DESC';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using phpMyAdmin version 4.2.3 (English) and I simply updated the sort order variable on line 488 in the DatabaseInterface.class.php file which resides in the Libraries directory. The line number (and possibly the file) may vary in other versions.

> ```
> public function getTablesFull($database, $table = false,
>     $tbl_is_group = false,  $link = null, $limit_offset = 0,
>     limit_count = false, $sort_by = 'Name', $sort_order = 'DESC',
>     $tble_type = null
> ```

The variable $sort_order was equal to 'ASC' when I opened the file.  Since changing it to DESC and uploading via FTP, the sort order for my table (which is uniquely keyed on date (DATETIME) is always DESC (most recently added records first).

Not sure if this is the best solution for all cases, but it suits my needs.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

None of the above answer work for me, I am using PHPMyAdmin 5.2.0

You can edit the below file for PHPMyAdmin and set the sort order as **DESC**

Filepath: `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Config/Settings.php`
function: `setTablePrimaryKeyOrder()`

Just set the setting variables as below at the start of the `setTablePrimaryKeyOrder()` function.

```
$settings['TablePrimaryKeyOrder'] = 'DESC';
```

and you're good to GO!!

Comment: You should find your config file and edit it, not change the code. Next time you update the phpmyadmin software your change will not be there and stop working.