# How sort results in PHPMyAdmin in table with no autoincrement field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table has a key but it's not autoincrement and I cant create and autoincrement field in this table. So I want to sort the results DESCENDING in the order they were inserted.

I cant create any field like data_row_was_inserted... Usually when I have a table with an autoincrement field I can just click over it and PHPMyAdmin sorts the table results in order they were inserted.

Thank you all!

PS: I know there must be someway to do that without creating any field cause when I open the table in PHPMyAdmin it automattically displays the results in ASCENDING order they were inserted but I want to display then in DESCENDING order. It proves that MySQL stores that information somewhere.

Comment: What would be the reason not to include a field with your order? For instance date of entry or a number when you add an new row. Normaly you would do something like SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY column_name DESC. I think phpmyadmin you use you primary key to sort. So, you could use your primary key column_name and then add DESC in the order column.

Comment: You can create a DATETIME field for each row and order the results by it.

Comment: ASCENDING order not == natural order.  It might just seem like the default is ascending.  You need to use an `ORDER BY` on a specific column. created date, auto increment, etc.

Comment: Perhaps this will clearify the point that phpmyadmin doesn't use a default way of sorting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959633/how-can-i-set-a-default-sort-for-tables-in-phpmyadmin-i-e-always-primary-key

Comment: I cant create new fields Sir. I need to keep the table as it is and I am very sure somehow this can be done cause naturally phpmyadmin already dispalys the results ordered by insert order event if I do not have an index in my table (autoincremente)

Answer (score 1):

Build a manual query and then bookmark it Or go to table then click on `Operations` tab on top, at `Operations` page find `Alter table order by`, then chose your column.

Operations tab: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wt5G.png

`Alter table order by` inside operations tab:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLHCu.png

Comment: did you read the comments above? He needs to define which column he will use to sort before he can use the order by.

Comment: I cant create new fields Sir. I need to keep the table as it is and I am very sure somehow this can be done cause naturally phpmyadmin already dispalys the results ordered by insert order event if I do not have an index in my table (autoincremente)