# How to create trigger "ORDER BY"

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I want to order my table `Jogadores` by `Total` value which I can achieve by writing this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `Jogadores` ORDER BY  `Total` DESC ;
```

My question is how do I use this as a trigger every time I edit a `Total` value or insert a new row?

I'm using phpMyAdmin

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. I am going to assume you want your table sorted in that fashion for when you retrieve it. If that is true, you can sort it upon retrieval rather than altering the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM Jogadores
ORDER BY Total DESC;
```

Comment: That's almost the same i had.

I want to see the table order by Total column everytime i open it...

It's by default order by ID

Comment: It is, for lack of a better word, destructive to your database to re-order by altering the table. Instead, inside phpMyAdmin, click the SQL tab, and paste in the SELECT query I suggested above. Then click go.

Comment: Better than running the SQL query directly, just click on the Total column header to tell phpMyAdmin to sort by that in the Browse view (click a second time to reverse the sort order, if desired). No need to write or copy and paste any SQL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why? That's not usually how SQL databases work
2. What if some totals are the same? What is the second way to sort them?
3. It's also usually not a good idea to store a total in your operational db. Is this a data warehouse?
4. It would probably be easier to add an index on `total` and create a view to order by that column.

Comment: 1.Total is a int value and i want to see the table with the highest values first
2.If the totals are the same it doesn't matter the order
3.I also have a auto-increment ID column...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the new comments, what you want is not doable. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959633/how-can-i-set-a-default-sort-for-tables-in-phpmyadmin-i-e-always-primary-key).

---

#### Original content:

As others have said, the physical order of the rows in the table doesn't matter since you can always sort when querying. If you're thinking of [clustered indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html), then all you need to do is define your primary key properly.

> The InnoDB term for a **primary key** index. InnoDB table storage is organized based on the values of the primary key columns, to speed up queries and sorts involving the primary key columns. For best performance, choose the primary key columns carefully based on the most performance-critical queries. Because modifying the columns of the clustered index is an expensive operation, choose primary columns that are rarely or never updated.

So a clustered index would achieve what you want, but it is probably not what you actually need. Just so you know, the clustered index speedups are practically zero if you're dealing with less than a million or so rows (rough estimate).

Comment: I don't know about other databases but in Oracle and SQL Server the only way to guarantee the order of returned records is to add an `ORDER BY` to the SELECT. Not even creating a clustered index will guarantee this.