# MySQL - Automatic ordering by ID not working

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm using MySQL database to store student projects (every single project has its own unique ID, as the first screenshot shows).

[image: Screenshot1]

The 'ID' column is set as **auto_increment** and **PRIMARY KEY**.

All projects must be ordered (only) by their ID ascending. But every time I insert a new project into my database and set lower value in the 'Year' field (lower value than I entered last time, when I was inserting my previous project), my projects become automatically ordered by this 'Year' field (as shown on the second screenshot).

[image: Screenshot2]

Is there any way, how to set my table for automatic ordering all newly added projects only by the 'ID' column? Yeah, I know that I can change the ordering with `ALTER TABLE tablename ORDER BY columnname ASC;`after I place every new record, but can it be done automatically?

Thx to everyone who helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q: Is there any way, how to set my table for automatic ordering all newly added projects only by the 'ID' column?

A: There is no "automatic ordering" in a MySQL table.  (Some storage engines, such as InnoDB, are "index organized" structures, and do store rows in order by the cluster key.) But this organization does not define or specify the order of rows returned by a SELECT statement.

Without an ORDER BY clause on a SELECT statement, then the MySQL server can return rows in *any* order it chooses to. There is no guarantee of any "automatic" or "default" ordering.

When we run a SQL SELECT statement without an ORDER BY clause, we do observe that rows tend to be returned in a consistent order.  This behavior isn't guaranteed, and it isn't "automatic".

This consistent "ordering" behavior we observe is due to the MySQL server performing a consistent set of operations, on a consistent set of data.

Performing an `ALTER TABLE` statement to rebuild the entire table is *not* the solution to the "automatic ordering" issue.

If you want the MySQL server to return rows in a specific order, then the solution is to **add an ORDER BY clause** to the SELECT statement.

The client that executes the SELECT statement is free to do whatever it wants with the rows it retrieves. The client can perform operations such as filtering, ordering, or whatever, to come up with what gets returned in the user interface.

Some clients (like the mysql command line) don't implement any functions for "filtering" or "ordering" rows, so the only way for the client to specify an order that rows should be returned in is the ORDER BY clause on statement itself. (The MySQL command line client returns rows in the user interface in the same order that they are retrieved.)

I expect that phpMyAdmin does the same thing, it displays the rows in the same order that they are returned from the MySQL server.

Comment: Thank you spencer7593 for explanation, now it seems to be much clearer for me. Also my problem seems to be solved.

Comment: I just had the same issue happened to my table, too. My newly added 22nd row was supposed to be at the bottom. But it appeared at the top because of the same issue. Please kindly advise on whether this mis-order issue in phpMyAdmin would affect the performance of the my queries. Thank you.

Comment: @IanY.: There is no "bottom" row or "top" row in a table.  (In relational database theory, tuples in a relation are *unordered*.) In practice, that means there is no order to the rows in a table. The relational database is free to store rows in any order. (Note that an `INSERT` statement does not have any syntax that supports specifying *where* in the table a row should be stored... at the beginning before any other row, or after a particular row. With the MySQL InnoDB storage engine, rows are stored in index order by  primary key. But this is an InnoDB implementation detail.

Comment: @IanY.  If we want rows returned from a SELECT statement (and running a SELECT statement is exactly how phpMyAdmin gets rows to display in the interface), we need to add an `ORDER BY` to   the SELECT statement. Without an ORDER BY, MySQL is free to return rows in any order. But with MySQL, we do observe some consistent behavior.  But that consistency is not a guarantee. The order of rows in a table doesn't have much of an impact on performance, nowhere near as much as missing or inappropriate indexes does... and we're talking here about tables with 22 million or 22 thousand rows, not 22 rows.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks a lot for letting me know that the performance of my queries isn't affected.

Answer (score 1):

Order in query results should be determined by the ORDER clause. Don't rely on default order applied by phpmyadmin (or some other tool).

You have to distinct retrieving from inserting/updating.

About automatic order INTO phpmyadmin, maybe using bookmarks on queries : [How can I set a default sort for tables in PHPMyAdmin (i.e. always "Primary key - Descending")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959633/how-can-i-set-a-default-sort-for-tables-in-phpmyadmin-i-e-always-primary-key)

Comment: Ok, thanks for quick response man, however, what do you exactly mean with 'distinct retrieving from inserting/updating'? Isn't there any way to go except SELECT * FROM `projekty` ORDER BY `projekty` . `id` ASC? Thx a lot.

Comment: @FilipCZ Im' not sure what he meant by that "distinct" statement, but to address your second question... No, there is no way to guarantee ordering other than to use an `ORDER BY` in a select; "rows" in a table do not have any inherent or guaranteed order in most RDBMS. I'm not even convinced phpMyAdmin is ordering by your year field, since "1/2" would come before "2015/2016"; my guess would be it is keeping new rows in some sort of list/stack (pushing newer rows to the front of the list).

Comment: Nope. You may use bookmarks in order to avoid retyping the same query, including order by, INTO phpmyadmin. But as the order will change (at each insert / update), you HAVE TO use order clause in select, even using the "alter table ... order" trick. That's simply what I meant; the use of "distinct" word in a SQL context may be confusing, I admit.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations, guys. Problem is now solved.