# auto order by ID in mySQL query result

Tags: mysql, sorting, record, keyword

I'm trying to solve an issue. When I write a query

```
SELECT ID, STOCK_ID, FILE_NAME FROM motor_images where STOCK_ID = 25
```

It does not sort my record. It shows random order. I want to sort it as per ID. I've also tried ORDER BY keyword but it does not work. Please help.

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y37O.png)

Comment: If you've tried `ORDER BY`, please edit your question to include that attempt. MySQL is not obligated to return things in any order unless asked to.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Also [mcve]. Also always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add keywords you discover to your searches. If find no answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Automatic ordering by ID not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553993/mysql-automatic-ordering-by-id-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

if your id isn't an auto generated int; it will sort by strings meaning 1,2,3...123, 124,125 etc will be ordered as 
1,123,124,125,2,3 etc.

what you need to do in this case is use a cast by int

```
SELECT id, stock_id, file_name FROM motor_images WHERE stock_id = 25 ORDER BY CAST(id as UNSIGNED)
```

Keep in mind the UNSIGNED is an integer; read more in the mysql documentation on casting. I could be wrong but there's no other reason I could think of that would cause the ids not to order correctly. http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: Please look attached snap and advise what is the order in result

Comment: can you screen it with the order by id results and the schema?